# Connection name 'SQL' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty

Tags: asp.net

Please i have been seeing this error:

> The connection name 'SQL' was not found in the applications
>   configuration or the connection string is empty.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.

I know for a fact that the connection name "SQL" exists and it works properly on my local machine.

I started seeing this error after i fixed this other error on my deployment server:

> Compiler Error Message: BC31007: Unable to open module file
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

by setting up the access rights as suggested [here](http://falhan.net/?p=152)

Please i would appreciate any help on this.

thanks!

Deployment Environment : Windows Server 2003, .net 4.0 
Development Environment: Widows 7, .net 4.0

Please note: The deployed application has been working perfectly well on site, for over 3 months up till last Friday evening.

The client claims nothing on the server or in their environment has changed.

My Web Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="LoginMode" value="2" />
        <add key="CustomeModules" value="True" />
        <add key="TopCallersRefeshInterval" value="600" />
        <add key="OperatorAccountName" value="" />
        <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=C:\TempImageFiles\;"/>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SQL" connectionString="server=.\SQL2008;database=xxxxxx;uid=xxxxxx;pwd=xxxxxxxxxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="SQLCustom" connectionString="server=.\SQL2008;database=xxxxxx;uid=xxxxxx;pwd=xxxxxxxxxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
     <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
     <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
     </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" explicit="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /></assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                                <remove value="login.aspx" />
                <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
                <remove value="default.aspx" />
                <remove value="index.html" />
                <remove value="index.htm" />
                <remove value="Default.asp" />
                <remove value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="home.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <handlers>
            <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your web.config pls.

Comment: @Jon Egerton, i have added the web.config

Comment: And the relevant section of the web.config of the deployment server?

Comment: @gerd yes this solution has been working fine for over 3 months at the clients site

Comment: Have you tried to check the event logs for the stacktrace?

Comment: @ssilas777 will try it out on Monday ... but i have my doubts.

Comment: @WilliamNiu have checked all log traces. the error is the same.

Comment: You probably want to find out the stacktrace of the error to nail down the exact place for the problem. If needed, use a remote debugger.

Comment: One very likely cause of sudden new problems is Winz auto-update. I encountered it before.

Comment: i have the assurance from their IT support that no Auto-Updates are enabled on that box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But, are you trying to connect to the remote database (i.e., the database on the deployment server) or to a local database.

Maybe somebody has touched the access privileges to the database...

By the way, how did you fixed the original error?

Comment: It's a local database. a local database. I fixed the initial error by granting access to a few system accounts as recommended http://falhan.net/?p=152

Comment: I'm also using MS SQL Server 2008 and I'm not using the `ProviderName` `System.Data.SqlClient` but `System.Data.EntityClient` in the connection string. Can you try this change? Maybe you have to add the reference to that to your project.

Comment: It is also possible that your local database is using windows authentication, instead its own authentication, while the remote database was the opposite. Just in case, my complete ConnectionString is `<add name="MyDBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />` ([more info](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008))

Comment: no. See this solution has been working fine for over 3 months on site. It begins to act up all of a sudden. I have not made any change to the solution, and the client claims their environment has not changed. IF the solution had never worked...i would have tried all your options....but it has worked for a while with existing config. My question is given the errors i listed, why should this happen?

Comment: I understand, but you are telling that you are using a local database, not the deployment one, right? I imagine you have take it into account...

Comment: it is sql server 2008 express. its on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

Delete every file(s) with .config format i.e. "web.user.config" but "web.config".

I hope it's help :)

Comment: i only deploy with web.config, no other config used on site

Answer (score 0):

Clear out the temp folder on your server. Recompile, redeploy and see if that fixes it for you. Also:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <clear />
     <remove name="SQL"/>
     <add name="SQL" 
         connectionString="server=.\SQL2008;database=xxxxxx;uid=xxxxxx;pwd=xxxxxxxxxx;"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      .....
</connectionStrings>
```

If that does not work, try a remote debugging session:

[How to: Set Up Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx)

Comment: +1 They're located at:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<.Net version>\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `</clear>` under your connection strings in web.config

```
connectionStrings>
   <clear />
     <add name="SQL" connectionString="server=.\SQL2008;database=xxxxxx;uid=xxxxxx;pwd=xxxxxxxxxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      .....
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Will try it on Monday...but i have my doubts. Why will a system which was working perfectly well all of a sudden just develop issues first with ASP.net compile error, then next with connectionString?